# Computation Expression for constructing complex object graph

Tags: f#, computation-expression

Given the following types:

```
type Trip = {
  From: string
  To: string
}

type Passenger = {
   Name: string
   LastName: string
   Trips: Trip list
}
```

I'm using the following builders:

```
type PassengerBuilder() = 
  member this.Yield(_) = Passenger.Empty

  [<CustomOperation("lastName")>]
  member __.LastName(r: Passenger, lastName: string) = 
    { r with LastName = lastName }

  [<CustomOperation("name")>]
  member __.Name(r: Passenger, name: string) = 
    { r with Name = name }

type TripBuilder() = 
  member __.Yield(_) = Trip.Empty

  [<CustomOperation("from")>]
  member __.From(t: Trip, f: string) = 
    { t with From = f }

  // ... and so on
```

to create records of type `Passenger`, like so:

```
let passenger = PassengerBuilder()
let trip = TripBuilder()

let p = passenger {
  name "john"
  lastName "doe"
}

let t = trip {
  from "Buenos Aires"
  to "Madrid"
}
```

how would I go about combining the `PassengerBuilder` and the `TripBuilder` so that I can achieve this usage?

```
let p = passenger {
    name "John"
    lastName "Doe"
    trip from "Buenos Aires" to "Madrid"
    trip from "Madrid" to "Paris"
}
```

that returns a `Passenger` record like:

```
{
   LastName = "Doe"
   Name = "John"
   Trips = [
       { From = "Buenos Aires"; To = "Madrid" }
       { From = "Madrid"; To = "Paris" }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What would be the result type of such expression?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin sorry, edited.

Comment: Wait, but that's not how `Passenger` type is declared. Do you want to return a different type? Or do you mean to change the definition of `Passenger`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin sorry, I might be missing something, but yes, the `Passenger` type only has `Name`, `LastName`, and a `Trip list`, which is what the bottom example is showing.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I don't want to change the type, I want to know how can I combine the two builders so that I can use the `TripBuilder` to build `Trip`s and pass those onto the `PassengerBuilder` so that it assigns those `Trip`s to the `Passenger` record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any reason why you want to use computation expression builder? Based on your example, it does not look like you're writing anything computation-like. If you just want a nice DSL for creating trips, then you could quite easily define something that lets you write:

```
let p = 
  passenger [
    name "John"
    lastName "Doe"
    trip from "Buenos Aires" towards "Madrid"
    trip from "Madrid" towards "Paris"
  ]
```

This is pretty much exactly what you asked for, except that it uses `[ .. ]` instead of `{ .. }` (because it creates a list of transformations). I also renamed `to` to `towards` because `to` is a keyword and you cannot redefine it.

The code for this is quite easy to write and follow:

```
let passenger ops = 
  ops |> List.fold (fun ps op -> op ps)
    { Name = ""; LastName = ""; Trips = [] } 

let trip op1 arg1 op2 arg2 ps = 
  let trip = 
    [op1 arg1; op2 arg2] |> List.fold (fun tr op -> op tr)
      { From = ""; To = "" }
  { ps with Trips = trip :: ps.Trips }

let name n ps = { ps with Name = n }
let lastName n ps = { ps with LastName = n }
let from n tp = { tp with From = n }
let towards n tp = { tp with To = n }
```

That said, I would still consider using normal F# record syntax - it is not that much uglier than this. The one drawback of the version above is that you can create passengers with empty names and last names, which is one thing that F# prevents you from!

Comment: I like this solution a lot. I'll give it a try. I was using computation expressions because I wanted to understand them and learn how to use them, but you're right that no real computation is being performed here.

Comment: I ended up removing the CE altogether and using this approach. Thank you Tomas!

Comment: @FedericoBerasategui I'm happy that you found this useful! That said, I completely understand trying to do this via CEs, they're fun :-).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is what you wanted, but nothing prevents you from creating a new operation called `trip` on your `PassengerBuilder`:

```
  [<CustomOperation("trip")>]
  member __.Trip(r: Passenger, t: Trip) = 
    { r with Trips = t :: r.Trips }
```

and then using it like this:

```
let p = passenger {
    name "John"
    lastName "Doe"
    trip (trip { from "Buenos Aires"; to "Madrid" })
    trip (trip { from "Madrid"; to "Paris" })
}
```

Arguably, you can even make it cleaner by dropping the `TripBuilder` altogether:

```
let p = passenger {
    name "John"
    lastName "Doe"
    trip { From = "Buenos Aires"; To = "Madrid" }
    trip { From = "Madrid"; To = "Paris" }
}
```

If this is somehow not what you wanted, then please specify how. That is, what is missing or what is extra in this solution.

Comment: That's good enough, I think, I'll have to live with the repetition of the `trip` word in `trip (trip { ... })`

Comment: Can you show an example of the builder for the second version?

Comment: It's the exact same `PassengerBuilder`. The expression `{ From = "a"; To = "b" }` is just standard F# syntax for creating an instance of `Trip`. The `PassengerBuilder.trip` operation accepts that instance as argument.